# How to add actions to Android Auto action card for audio

Tags: android, android-auto

I am implementing Android Auto into an existing music application. I would like to add the action button to the main action card for the audio player in auto to open the navigation drawer but I can't seem to figure out how to get there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Example of main action card can be viewed [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec-auto/audio-apps/main-consumption-view.html) and the button mentioned would be the one on the far left.

Comment: Please post the code related to the specific problem here. Outbound links tend to become unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom actions should be adding through PlaybackState and addCustomAction()

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html#addCustomAction(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html#addCustomAction(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

Important point, there is flags to indicate to auto if main page controller should keep empty space when "next" and "previous" are not enable.

```
private static final String SLOT_RESERVATION_SKIP_TO_NEXT =
        "com.google.android.gms.car.media.ALWAYS_RESERVE_SPACE_FOR.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT";
private static final String SLOT_RESERVATION_SKIP_TO_PREV =
        "com.google.android.gms.car.media.ALWAYS_RESERVE_SPACE_FOR.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS";
```

that you add at your MediaSessionCompat with setExtras() method.
With flags, custom actions are added in a second screen that you acceed in swiping main Auto audio meta screen.
With no flags, custom actions are added next to Play/Pause button.